# How to create IPhone's today view like list?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

How to create this type of scrolling animation, when top element move backward.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Start from `CustomScrollView`, calculate the animations.
You can use `GlobalsKeys` to find the height of element, to use it as maxExtend parameter.

[image]

full example is here: https://github.com/kherel/flutter_fun

Comment: Thanks bro. Glad that you like it. I wanted to make it for a long time.